Netvips Thumbnail does not preserve resolution or remove some parts of image
I'm using NetVips to create some diferent sizes of my image
This is my original img
And this is the result

This is my code:
    public static void GetThumbNail(
        string sourcePath,
        string targetPath,
        int width,
        int height,
        int R = 255,
        int G = 255,
        int B = 255)
    {
        if (targetPath == null)
            targetPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath), $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourcePath)}_Thumb{Path.GetExtension(sourcePath)}");
        Image main = Image.Black(width, height, 3);
        main = main + new[] { R, G, B };
        Image watermark = Image.Thumbnail(sourcePath, width, height);
        int top = (main.Height - watermark.Height) / 2;
        int left = (main.Width - watermark.Width) / 2;
        // extract related area from main image
        var baseImage = main.Crop(left, top, watermark.Width, watermark.Height);
        // composite the two areas using the PDF "over" mode
        var composite = baseImage.Composite(watermark, Enums.BlendMode.Over);
        // the result will have an alpha, and our base image does not..we must flatten
        // out the alpha before we can insert it back into a plain RGB JPG image
        composite = composite.Flatten();
        // insert composite back in to main image on related area
        var combined = main.Insert(composite, left, top);
        combined.WriteToFile(targetPath);
    }


Your code looks a bit confused. I think you've maybe got the watermark and the thumbnail mixed up. Where did you get this code sample from?

It was an inherited code. It was working until now. and totally lost about it, All i need is get an image, resize it to specific size and save resized version

Well there's stuff there to make a watermark and paste it over the image in the centre. All you need is Image.Thumbnail(sourcePath, width, height).WriteToFile(targetPath);

@jcupitt  Does Image.Thumbnail(sourcePath, width, height).WriteToFile(targetPath); preserve image ratio aspect ?

I'll write a proper reply.

It looks like you want to thumbnail to fit within a specified width x height, with the thumbnail being padded with a background colour if one dimension is too small, is that right?
You can use Thumbnail() to fit within a certain width x height, then Gravity() to expand in case one axis is too short.
I would try (untested):
Image
    .Thumbnail(sourcePath, width, height)
    .Gravity(Enums.CompassDirection.Centre, width, height, Enums.Extend.Background, new[] { R, G, B })
    .WriteToFile(targetPath);


Great it works but removing RGB array from Gravity seems my netvips does not suppors it, How Can I do to add backgroud color ?

It should work, perhaps I have the syntax wrong. https://kleisauke.github.io/net-vips/api/NetVips.Image.html#NetVips_Image_Gravity_NetVips_Enums_CompassDirection_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Nullable_NetVips_Enums_Extend__System_Double___

If you're keeping R, G, B as int, try new double[] { R, G, B }, or simply use the C#12 collection expression [R, G, B].

@kleisauke, can you please add an example how to make the background transparent?

@dennis_n Answered here: https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips/issues/243.
